# How do I echo string with bash command more in Perl?

Tags: perl, bash

This is what I tried:

```
my $s = "s" x 1000;
my $r = `echo $s |more`;
```

But it doesn't work, my program exits directly...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It does not work in your example, because you never print `$r`. The output is captured in the variable `$r`. By using `system()` instead, you can see the output printed to STDOUT, but then you cannot use the output as you (probably) expected.

Just do:

```
print $r;
```

Update: I changed `say` to `print`, since "echo" already gives you a newline.

To escape shell meta characters, as mentioned in the comments, you can use [quotemeta.](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html)

You should also be aware that `| more` has no effect when capturing output from the shell into a variable. The process is simply: `echo | more | $r`, and you might as well skip `more`.

Comment: How to escape the string when passing to bash?

Comment: You can use [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html). Or you can escape characters yourself, if you know what to look for.

Answer (score 3):

try with the [system()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) command :

```
my $s = "s" x 1000;
my $r = system("echo $s |more");
```

will display all your 's', and in `$r` you will have the result (0 in this case) of the command.

Comment: What if `$s` contains special characters ? Is there a function to do shell_escape alike stuff?

Comment: quotemeta is the wrong tool because it's for quoting regexp special characters, not shell special characters.